# How to change the calendar type in dateTimePicker?

Tags: datetimepicker

i try to change the calendar type in dateTimePicker from gregorian to hijri but i cant cuz the system calender type it's gregorian .

i try this code

```
 CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
 DateTimeFormatInfo info = ci.DateTimeFormat;
 dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
 dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = info.ShortDatePattern + " " + info.ShortTimePattern;
```

but not working !?

how i can change it in my App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN:

> The DateTimePicker control only supports Gregorian calendars.

But you can create a custom calendar, check out these articles (C#):

[Windows Hijri Calendar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23226/Windows-Hijri-Calendar)

[ASP.NET DatePicker User Control (Hijri / Gregorian)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570197/ASP-NET-DatePicker-User-Control)

[How to create a Hijri Calendar control in .Net Framework 2.0](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/276.html)

Answer (score 0):

DatetimePicker use the system calendar to change it you need to change the registry subkey

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
```

Dim reg As Registrykey=Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubkey("Control Panel\International\",True)
reg.SetValue("Calendar","Gregorian")
Dim sreg As Registrykey =Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubkey("Control Panel\International", True)
sreg.SetValue("sCalendar","GregorianCalendar")

You can choose any calendar in calendar list of your windows but make sure to write the proper spelling

It is important to change the cultureinfo to the culture using the specified Calendar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you explain your answer in more detail. I prefer to use C# language

Answer (score 0):

replace   "Gregorian" and "GregorianCalendar" with the name of the calendar you want to use .
spelling must be correct
your current system culture must support the calendar you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Imports Microsoft.Win32
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  Button1.Click         
 Dim Regk1 As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\International\", True)                          
 Regk1.SetValue("Calendar", "Gregorian") 
 Regk1.Close() Dim Regk2 As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\International", True) 
 Regk2.SetValue("sCalendar", "GregorianCalendar") 
 Regk2.Close() 
Dim Formatregk As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\International", True)       
Formatregk.SetValue("sShortDate", "dd/MM/yyyy") 
End Sub
```

Replace the "Gregorian" And "GregorianCalendar" with Calendar you want to use but be sure the new calendar is supported by the current culture